# Help to understand some investment comments?

Tags: investing

I am a foreigner in US and new to investment, and have trouble understanding a comment (http://seekingalpha.com/instablog/45557-rod-raynovich/2254972-fidelity-select-biotechnology-fund-fbiox-outperforms-biotech-etfs-ytd):

> There is a sell-off today as it is prudent to take some off after the huge runs. I see another rally in Dec.-Jan. time frame then only modest 10% gains for 2014.

Does "huge run" mean big increase in the fund's value, not big decrease or big change?

Does the first sentence mean that some prudent investors sell their shares after the big increase in the value of the fund?

What does "rally" mean in the second sentence?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A "run" means a period marked by a continuous trend, so technically it could be a sustained rise or fall, but in this context it means a rise. This is because the meaning of the first sentence is that after a major increase, some investors will sell some of their shares, [taking profit](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/profittaking.asp) as a means to reduce risk. "Rally" has a meaning similar to a "run", but it only refers to an increase.